# Magento 1.8.1 Bundled Products Price does Not update

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have 1.8.1 installed and having an issue with the bundled products.  When you add or subject items, the price does not change.  I am getting js errors and the price will not update.  Could somebody help let me know what I have configured wrong
I am getting these errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: taxCalcMethod is not defined
>       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reloadPrice' of undefined

Here is a snip of the error code

```
  <script>
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
bundle.reloadPrice();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you install a different theme?

Answer (score 5):

You need to include the following after the `<?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>` line in your template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle.phtml

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var bundle = new Product.Bundle(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
        var taxCalcMethod = "<?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getConfig()->getAlgorithm($_product->getStore()) ?>";
        var CACL_UNIT_BASE = "<?php echo Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::CALC_UNIT_BASE ?>";
        var CACL_ROW_BASE = "<?php echo Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::CALC_ROW_BASE ?>";
        var CACL_TOTAL_BASE = "<?php echo Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::CALC_TOTAL_BASE ?>";
        //]]>
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This code all ready added my file but also generate error on my page.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the exact error? Did you check the page html source that the above block is indeed included?

Comment: Works also in 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

a quick addition - this obviously works perfectly - the full path to the bundle file (just in case anyone ever wonders):

/public_html/app/design/frontend/YOUR_TEMPLATE/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type

Comment: explain your answer briefly.